# How to initialize a persistent variable in c

Tags: c, variables, persistent-storage

In `.h` file I have a persistent variable
`extern <Enum Datatype> __attribute__((section(".persist"))) state`

In `.c` file I have to initialize the variable `state` to one of the member of enum
Example:
`enum state = <One of the member of enum>`

If I try the above method the compiler throws the warning persistent variables cannot be initialized.

Note: The persistent variable is used for a test of PRE and POST usage of a system, hence initially in the application code I want the test to start from PRE.

Comment: Semi-educated guess: If the variable is persistent, that presumably means it keeps its value between runs.  If your code were allowed to initialize it, that would overwrite the persisted value, defeating the objective of marking it persistent.  I'm assuming the section name has semantics along the lines of what is suggested by the name.  I've not gone hunting down the formal meaning of the attribute.

Comment: Re "*Semi-educated guess*", That would be my guess as well. /// Re "*I've not gone hunting down the formal meaning of the attribute*", I have, and I can't find anything about this `.persist` section. Got docs for it? /// I also tried searching for the error message, but Google returns no match other than this page for `persistent variables cannot be initialized`.

Comment: There is an attribute `persistent` documented in GCC [Common Variable Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html) near the bottom, out of alphabetic sequence.  But that's not using `section`, if I'm reading the manual correctly.  The meaning of sections depends on the linker in use.

Comment: So to answer the question, you could initialize it by having a another program write a value to it when you want it initialized.

Comment: While it makes sense, not to allow initialization during startup, it should be possible to provide some initial content for that memory area during flashing the program. It might help if you told us what target and what toolset you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been referring to this [link](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/oxy/GUID-BB433107-FD4E-4D28-BB58-9D4A58955B1A-en-US-5/GUID-8BA3E193-B5F5-4ACD-A0FF-71ED46118F29.html), where it clearly says the following statement.

> Any object that needs to be persistent **cannot be assigned an initial value** when defined. **A warning will be issued** if you use the __persistent qualifier with an object **that is assigned an initial value**, and for that object, **the qualifier will be ignored.**

Another useful link would be [this](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/oxy/GUID-C4E60FF5-3DAB-44F1-BA61-4BD962D8F469-en-US-4/GUID-5FBFDC24-67FD-4C52-986A-C9C597563FB2.html), where it says that

> The persistent attribute specifies that the **variable should not be initialized** or cleared at startup. **Persistent data is not normally initialized by the C run-time.**

In summary, **persistent variable should not be initialized.**

There is a code snippet available in the above link, where it says how to 'safely initialize' the `persistent` variable. Just pasting the same here for easy reference.

```
#include <xc.h>

int last_mode __attribute__((persistent)); //declaring the persistent variable.

int main()
{
    if ((RCONbits.POR == 0) &&
        (RCONbits.BOR == 0)) {
      /* last_mode is valid */
   } else {
     /* initialize persistent data */
     last_mode = 0;
   }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The sole purpose of marking a variable as "persistent" is to prevent the startup code initialization of the variable. Thus it makes sense that the compiler does not allow initialization of such a variable.

If the variable really needs to be persistent (i.e. the value must be preserved over different runs of the application), then its value must be set by assignment within the code.